# How to toggle feature visibility by dependency

Tags: 2010, features

How can I hide a Web-scoped feature until a specific Site-scoped feature has been activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define feature dependencies cross scoped according to [Activation Dependencies and Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543162%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
In theory you can change the visibility once the site collection feature was enabled but you need to do the same for ever sub site that will be created.

From my point of view the best way would be if you check in a feature event receiver of the web scoped feature if the site collection feature is enabled.